# Dropzone.js no longer uploading multiple imgs to website on Android

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

Up until about a couple weeks ago, my web app was working great on desktop and mobile, using dropzone.js as a drag and drop means of uploading images.  Now suddenly on my Android device things have changed.

**When it was working:**

Member hit the upload button and was prompted to select which app to use to select the images for upload.  Typically default app was "Gallery" which doesn't allow for multiple selections, but when Google Photos was selected, multiple images could be selected and all images selected would upload.  With a tool tip I was able to advise users on Android to use Google Photos vice Gallery.

**Now**

Same scenario, including being able to ***select*** multiple images to upload.  However, when the "Done" button is pressed to initiate the upload, only the first image selected uploads.

Multiple uploads work as expected on desktop and iOS but for whatever reason something has changed with Android and/or Google Photos that for the life of me I can't figure out.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dgq50zc3/)

For those of you willing to take the time to help out, please try it on both your desk top and Android device to see the difference in behavior.

Also note that the .js included with the fiddle is for reference only and is being driven by the same file externally.

Please note the above fiddle doesn't actually upload the images anywhere, but it is the exact behavior I am having issues with.  The upload part of the script and db management is separate from this issue.

The actual structure when all located together is to have the following script:

```
<script src="js/dropzone.js"></script>
```

Thanks

Comment: So far the only workaround I have been able to come up with is to explore converting my site into a native / hybrid app using PhoneGap.  If anyone has any other suggestions, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is what I tried**
I've updated a bit the code.
https://jsfiddle.net/_jserodio/dgq50zc3/10/

**Here is what I tested**
In `Android 5.0` it works with `Google Chrome`.
But It didn't work with `Firefox` and/or `Lightning browser`.

> It's not supported for Android 4.x and bellow
>   http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-multiple